# Encrypt existing disk with LUKS?

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

I have get informed on how prepare a LUKS system & partitions, giving a key/passphrase, etc. But for a new fresh install of linux.

How to encrypt an already installed/configured linux system ?

**EDIT** I have made my linux system as a server. I need it crypted, and I would like to test encryption without to reinstall anything.

Comment: Unless it's LVM all data has to be moved to make room at the beginning for the LUKS header (2MiB). So it's not a straightforward / risk-free process. Tell us more about your setup (Partitions/RAID/LVM/...)

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks (you could post it as an answer). It's not LVM. I had to clone it to a machine with LVM. Or backup, erase disk with LVM and clone it back... That's my question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219447/deploy-duplicate-a-configured-customized-linux-on-another-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make another partition (or image file) with an encrypted fs for your data. Moving root on the fly to an encrypted fs on the same disk does not work.